# RedirectMatch > regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Any ideas why this isn't working?

RedirectMatch rule in an .htaccess file.

```
    RedirectMatch "(?:example.com)\/(?:images)\/(.*)(jp?g|bmp|png)" "http://www.example.com/assets/images/public/$1$2"
```

I've a feeling it boils down to the regex not being correct.

Desired outcome: 
Basically if a request is made for: 
http://www.example.com/images/some-logo.jpg
it get's pulled from here:
http://www.example.com/assets/images/public/some-logo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in need of a `RewriteRule` rather than `RedirectMatch`:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ /assets/images/public/$1 [L]
```